# How To Turn off mail notification blue envelope?

Tags: notification, evolution

I was wondering how to turn off the blue envelope notification in Ubuntu 14.04
it lights up perfectly, but it never turns off again. I need to manually delete notifications.

Even if I have read the email from evolution, this is a flaw in the notification system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove Evolution from the blue envelope notifications, open Evolution and open the Edit -> Plugin menu and disable the **Evolution Indicator**:

[image]

Alternatively, to completely get rid off the GNOME panel indicator applet for Evolution, just uninstall the following package, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution-indicator
```

Note: keeping the `mail-notification-evolution` package will still popup "x new messages" using `libnotify`.

Comment: does this also remove the popup notification? "x new messages"
because i like that. but i don't like a blue icon ;-)

Comment: I think so, but let me check if Evolution can just turn off the Envelope and keep the Notifications with a better way

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: isn't accepting not the same as upvoting ;-) others schould upvote right?!

Comment: As the OP, you should do both, see http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers